# Input from keyboard

Tags: java, user-input

I want to take values from user for this program, that is value for `Name`, `roll`, `salary` directly from an user.

How to do that?

```
 public class MethodOverloadingPractice {

    public void display(String name){
        System.out.println("Name is "+name);
    }

    public void display(String name, int roll){
        System.out.println("Name is " + name + "Roll is " + roll);
    }

    public void display(String name, int roll, double salary){
        System.out.println("Name is " + name + "Roll is " + roll + "Salary is " + salary);
    }      
}

class MOP{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    MethodOverloadingPractice obj = new MethodOverloadingPractice();
    obj.display("Jannatin");
    obj.display("Jannatin", 101);
    obj.display("Jannatin", 101, 150);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is this language?

Comment: this is for Java language

Answer (score 1):

You can read in a line from the command line using a `Scanner`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
String name = scanner.next();
String roll = scanner.next();
String salary = scanner.next();
scanner.close();
```